# Flat shader and transparency

Tags: shaders, transparency

I have to use flat shading in Blender, but I need to use transparency too, for the windows.

I can't use shadows or AO, I just need to visualize the flat shading and transparency in the viewport.

If there's a way to do this, please let me know.

My settings:

[image]

Expected in viewport:

[image: flat shading walls with transparent window]

My viewport:

[image]

Thanks in advance.